# É possível alterar o template/interface gráfica de um formulário no Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Andei pesquisando sobre e os resultando que consegui foram apenas recorrer ao WPF ao invés de usar WinForm, mas ainda tenho está duvida e acredito que seja possível, é possível alterar a template do software desenvolvido em Windows Forms?

Comment: Não entendi o que você deseja. De que template está falando? Informe melhor o objetivo.

Comment: Quando se desenvolve em Windows Forms independente da linguagem visual c++ ou Visual C# tem uma template padrão: [link](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/images/c2WindowsForm_ToolboxTab.gif), eu gostaria de saber se é possível alterar este template padrão do windows forms.

Comment: Ainda não entendi o que isto que quer mexer. Você tem que explicar de outra forma.

Comment: o Windows Forms tem uma TEMPLATE padrão, certo?? Como anexei um link no comentário anterior a barra de titulo do programa tem aquele padrão azul do windows e todos os objetos também, quando se desenvolve em WPF você pode alterar via XML está interface desejo fazer o mesmo só que em WinForm ou até mesmo importar...

Comment: @bigown Me parece que ele quer mudar o tema/look and feel da uma aplicaçao feita em Windows Forms.

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição pode ser mesmo, bem observado, vamos ver se ele confirma.

Comment: @Pedro, sei que ha algumas bibliotecas pagas que facilitam isso, mas no Windows Forms isso é um pouco complicado. Em um projeto que participei onde era necessario modificar o tema, a soluçao encontrada foi usar imagens e bordas sobrepondo os elementos originais (botoes, tabelas, etc), e delegar os eventos aos elementos originais quando as imagens eram clicadas.

Comment: Exatamente isso @RenatoDinhaniConceição e bigown, fuçando por aqui achei umas dll's e consegui importar alguns objetos mas nada que altere o tema por completo... Essas bibliotecas pagas você quis dizer que não era para WinFOrms né?? Humm, uma boa solução @Renato! o Nome do pacote das dll's citado acima é "DotNetToolbars", Obrigado pessoal!

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição foi bem trabalhoso ein? rsrsrs...

Comment: Com WPF isto é fácil.

Comment: Bom pessoal consegui bons resultados, achei uma boa forma para mudar tema e tem vários, nem precisa instalar nada... Quem quiser explorar da uma olhadinha no video explica certinho: [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6IeBysaVLk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem algumas bibliotecas como o [QIOS](http://www.qiosdevsuite.com/), o [Krypton](http://www.componentfactory.com/) e o [DotNetBar](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/) que permitem alterar o look da aplicação, mas não tenho certeza se ele se aplica em forms também.

Pelos meus usos desses componentes eu sei que há modos de você, por exemplo, retirar as bordas de um formulário e adicionar os botões dele no lugar dos botões originais do windows, isso significa que você "mascara" a aplicação, mas no fundo o template é o mesmo, e eles tem umas documentações bem legais que dá pra você trabalhar.

[Este site](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2012/04/27/Customizing-the-Look-and-Feel-or-your-Windows-Forms-Applications.aspx) tem uma lista de modelos que podem alterar o skin de um form e seus controles também, porém nunca utilizei.

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado! ontem após de uma bela fuçada na net achei diversos modos de alterar os temas... Esse "QIOS" e "Krypton" não conhecia apenas o DotNetBar, mas me restou algumas duvidas pois você já matou uma delas, como pensava que alterava por completo o tema, mas não apenas "mascara" como vc disse. Obrigado!